# How to See Stats When I Get Limit For Specific Review Task

Tags: support, review

I have applied daily review task for one of the review tasks. So I can not click on that task (i.e. Late Answers) because of I am at limit. However if I don't click on that review task how I will able to see my stats?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to go into the queue to see the stats page:

> [image]

The link is https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats in case you just want to go there directly.