# Permit access to review stats and history even after hitting daily limit

Tags: feature-request, review

When a user exceeds a daily limit in a review queue it would be nice to be able to access *Stats* and *History* tabs of the queue by clicking the name of the queue.

Would it be possible disable only the *Review* tab? Sometimes I feel I would like to get back to some questions/answers I reviewed and going back by changing url address is not so much user-friendly.

Comment: By the way, [there is a workaround](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163310/152859) you know. :)

Comment: It is nice, but why shouldn't this be possible without using a workaround? The direct access would be certainly the best option.

Comment: Sure, +1 from me, but feature requests might wait for looong time, and many never get attention.

Comment: I don't really mind. I use bookmarks in my explorer now. I'm just pointing out my experience with the user interface.